# How can I pass result for int function to void function

Tags: c

```
int *mA(int x){
    int *arr[x], i = 0;
    while(i<x){
        arr[x]=i;
        printf("%d ", arr[x]);
        i++;
    }return arr;
}

void fA(int *arr, int x){
    int j=0;
    while(j<x){
        printf("%d ", arr[x]);
        j++;
    }
```

`mA` is the function which creates array with the input length. If user inputs 5 as length then the array will be assigned as 1 2 3 4 5. The reason why I have put `printf("%d ", arr[x]);` in `mA` function is because I wanted to test whether it successfully assign 0 into array or not and as a result, it worked. However in `fA`, it shows nothing. I am using call by reference method but due to my limited knowledge I can't solve this error. if `mA` function successfully assigned 0 into array then `fA` function should be able to read and display the result, but what is the problem here?

Comment: You return the address of a local array. That is not allowed as the lifetime of that array ends after leaving the function.

Comment: @Gerhardh Then should I change return arr; to return *arr;?

Comment: No, you need to allocate memory for your data. `*arr` is same as `arr[0]` and only contains 1 integer.

Comment: @Gerhardh I will check first. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gerhardh I have read the article and it was really helpful. Thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

Your probleme come from:

```c
int *arr[x];
```

here you create a pointer to an array not allocated with `malloc`or any allocator function, then you can't return it. To solve this change:

```c
int *arr[x];
// to
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * x); // or any allocator function
```

When you have use this array or end your programme you need to free the memory allocated to it as:

```
free(arr);
```

that can be call every where if you have the pointer of your array

Comment: It is not a pointer to array, it is *array of pointers*.